# Отправка формы с последующей заменой value

Tags: javascript, form

Проблема в то что при первом клике меняется `value` с `add` на `delete` но форма не отправляется при повторном клике меняется `value` на `add` и форма отправляется с `add`.

Как сделать правильно?   Клик > Отправка > Замена

**Форма**

```
<form id="favorite" method="GET" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="iframe">
    <input type="submit" id="fav" name="favorite" value="add"/>
</form>
```

**js**

```
$(function(){$('#fav').click(
    function() {
        $(this).val() == "add" ? delete_item() : add_item();
    });
});
function delete_item() {
    $('#fav').val("delete");
}
function add_item() {
    $('#fav').val("add");
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, расставляйте запятые. Без них сложно понять, что отправляется, что не отправляется, а что меняется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

по логике скрипта,  если содержимое == "add"(как идет изначально) то менять содержимое на "delete".
а если второй клик, то содержимое уже будет "delete" изменено на "add".

чтобы форма не отправлялась сделай return false
либо: preventDefaul()